# replace a character from only font style bold

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I'm new to android and I'm trying to replace a character from bold style  at a specific character in a arraylist string. What I'm doing is:

```
String myName = "76492";
```

This is my search string and i want to search this string in to the arraylist then i want to bold those character when getting on the `arraylist.Arraylist` string is 78758,3660,56798,6514,90679.

```
TextView txtf = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
TextView txtS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);                                    
TextView txtT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);

String str= myName.replaceAll("6", "<b>6</b>");                                 
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(str);
txtf.setText(text);
txtS.setText(text);
txtT.setText(text);
txt1.setText(text);
txt2.setText(text);
```

But this is replace all `Textview` String by the *76492* string  with match charater bold style. 1879 search string this is replace old string but i donot want this type replace .iI want only specific position character change in bold style

Comment: what is the problem exactly? and what is your `strlottery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style name="boldText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

</style>
```

Paste this code snippet in your style.xml which is in valuse folder under layout.

```
txtf.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.boldText);
```

This line of code is for your text view appear as a bold.

Comment: Thanks fro response but i want to use bold style on dynamic string and only match character bold not all textview string..

Comment: Yes.First set the string to textview and then apply the bold property for textview..

Comment: i want to my search string replace all textview string with bold "6" character

Comment: This is based on lottery concept

Comment: String toShow ="<font: bold ...>"+"bold string"+"</font>";
Html.fromHtml(toShow); use this line of code instead of to make bold

Comment: Change Your code into below                                    String str= myName.replaceAll("6", "<b>"+"6"+"</b>");                                 
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(str);                                  It is working fine...

Comment: Thanks .This code has been used but it is replacing all string of  different textview

Comment: Ofcourse.,it will replace all strings for different text views.........If you want for specific text view do the bold for within the setText method

Comment: thanks..yaa i want specific text character bold on current position and its replace only bold for current character of different textview ..

Answer (score 1):

Use spans. Then you can specify parts of your string and assign any format or color you want. Have a look at [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177#).
Edit: For clarification: With spans you don't replace the characters. Use some string method to find the position of the characters you want to change to bold and create a span on these positions and assign bold format to that span.

Comment: thanks..for response.iI do not want replace my string from spanned new string.I want only bold of specific character